# windows command pattern match failing

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Problem :

I have the below command which runs the console file and parallely executes the dll files

This below command fails stating that the file is not at the source. Basically it says the file is not found at `..\bin\unittest` path

```
%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /Logger:trx --Parallel "..\bin\UnitTest\*unity*tests*.dll"
```

The above command works fine when i run for the single file like the below. The below cmd works fine.

```
%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /Logger:trx --Parallel "..\bin\UnitTest\Lang.unity.tests.dll"
```

So I believe the problem is due to the pattern matching with unity tests. I tried multiple workaround but the command fails

Can any one point out why the command fails ?

Comment: Maybe the tool cannot resolve wildcards, but you could put a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) around to do that job…

Answer (score 0):

A quick google finds these links:

- [VSTest.Console.exe command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019)

> [test file names] - Run tests from the specified files. Separate multiple test file names with spaces.
> Examples: mytestproject.dll, mytestproject.dll myothertestproject.exe

- [Support wildcards in filenames for vstest.console.exe](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1663)

> Q: is this done. I see that there was a PR above that was merged with this support
>
> A: Yes this is complete
>
> Q: Do you perhaps now in which version this improvement has been included?
>
> A: Here is the latest version that is released https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/releases/tag/v16.3.0-preview-20190808-03

So I'm going to go out on a limb and say either space-delimit the filenames, or upgrade to a newer version of vstest.console.exe...